# Replace multiple strings in multiple files

Tags: windows-7, windows, search, find-and-replace, multiple-instances

I think the title speaks for itself. How can I replace multiple strings in multiple files?

For example, I have the following strings:

```
home.php, blog.php, forums.php, contact.php, etc.
```

And I want to replace all of them with these, respectively:

```
home.html, blog.html, forums.html, contact.html, etc.
```

These are strings *in files*.
They happen to look like file names because they are in HTML hyperlinks.
There are hundreds of occurrences and I want to replace them all at once.

I'm using Windows 7 OS.
Is there any native Windows command or off-the-shelf software that can do this?
I can develop a programmatic solution, e.g., in PHP,
because I can have all strings in JSON, XML or array formats, but that's a last resort.

Comment: Are you talking about replacing strings _in files_, or in file ***names***? If the latter, you're talking about _renaming_ files, and I suggest that you search this site (and maybe also the web) for that.

Comment: What Operating System? This is trivial with default \*nix tools, but I think you'll have to install something or write up a simple script on Windows.

Comment: I'm using Window 7.

Comment: @G-Man I want to replace the strings in files, not the file names. In my example they look like file names because I'm trying to replace the hyperlinks from HTML.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://superuser.com/a/89984/252481)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use a batch file to recursively replace a string in files?](http://superuser.com/q/637904/354511) See also [Script for modifying file content in specified files](http://superuser.com/q/648749/354511) and [Script to find certain words and delete those lines in a file](http://superuser.com/q/798906/354511).

Answer (score 0):

A simple array of strings will do if you have any programming skills.
Create a for each loop (or for loop throughout the whole array) and recreate the string by dividing the string with '.' as delimiter, so that `home.php` becomes `home` and `php`, replacing second item and then creating string from substrings again.
If you only intend to rename php files to html files, you can simply replace every occurence of `php` with `html`.

This can be achieved with every scripting and programming language possible, so let us know if you need simple example in language which syntax you're familiar with.

Comment: I personally know how to do this in PHP. I can create a loop, catch all files from directory and open/save the content. I'm looking more for a software, if exists. If it does not exists, then I probably would write the script. ;)